# MySQL result for current date and if records don't exist return last 3 records

Tags: mysql

I have the following query that gives me the records for the current date:

```
select * from tickets where updated >=CURDATE()
```

To me it seems like I would have an `OR` condition to say get last 3 records however as far I know that can only be applied to success results with a `LIMIT` clause. Maybe I'm over thinking this so a nudge in the right direction would help.

Comment: Did you get the right answer to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really don't want to do two queries, then this will do it for you.

```
SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE updated = CURDATE()
UNION 
(SELECT DISTINCT * FROM tickets WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE updated = CURDATE()) 
ORDER BY 
  updated DESC 
LIMIT 3)
```

The problem with the other answers is if updated = CURDATE() is true, they will still return the updated ones as well as the not updated today (and they only return 3) - which I don't believe is what you want.

My query makes sure as a matter of the NOT EXISTS that you select one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correct,

```
select * from tickets where updated >=CURDATE() 
UNION DISTINCT
(select * from tickets where ORDER BY updated DESC LIMIT 3)
```

Should get you everything updated >=CURDATE(). But if there aren't at least 3 values, it will get the most recent until there are 3.

The `UNION` statement just 'glues' the two queries together, and the `DISTINCT` statement simple combines the rows that are identical.

The parentheses are required to bind the `LIMIT 3` to only the bottom select only.

Comment: Not sure he wants to limit updated today to 3 records, nor from my reading does he want to show both if they exist - it's one or the other.

Comment: The above does not limit updated today to 3. The `limit 3` will bind to the second select only. However, your point is taken about being one or the other. Asker wasn't clear.

Comment: From the manual "To apply ORDER BY or LIMIT to an individual SELECT, place the clause inside the parentheses that enclose the SELECT:" - I was of the impression that when you use a UNION, the LIMIT BY will be of the whole query unless in parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the last 3 records that were updated?  Use an ORDER BY and LIMIT BY

```
select * from tickets where updated >= CURDATE() order by updated desc limit 3
```